# GC Cloud Build: Exception in Remote-Builder hello world

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I try to set up remote builde of my AppEngine app with [Remote Builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder) image.
Here is my cloudbuild.yaml:
`steps:
- name: gcr.io/{PROJECT_NAME}/remote-builder
  env:
  - ZONE=us-east1-b
  - INSTANCE_NAME=Remote_Cloud_Build
  - INSTANCE_ARGS=--image-project cos-cloud --image-family cos-stable`

I've taken this values from remote builder [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/master/remote-builder/examples/cloudbuild.yaml)

But when I try to deploy it with `gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml`
 I get an error:
 `/bin/run-builder.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found`

Could you please help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to windows style `run-builder.sh` file ending. I've changed it from CRLF to LF and it works